# Linear functional vs. map

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

A few days ago we were briefly discussing Taylor's theorem in higher dimensions in the lecture. Referring to the expression

$f(x)=f(a)+Df(a)(x-a)+$higher order

the lecturer said that in general $Df$ is a *linear functional*, but it becomes a *map* if $f$ is defined on a Banach space.

Now that I look at my notes, I don't really understand the statement. Is there a difference between a linear functional and a map? (in particular, why is it of importance here?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear functional is usually an element of the dual vector space, e.g. if you're working with real vector spaces, it's a map $f : V \to \mathbb R$. A map is just a function between sets.

EDIT : It might be that your author thinks of functionals as *continuous* linear maps, and in the case of Banach spaces it is not always the case that linear maps are continuous. Either way, I would need to read that part of the book to be more precise.

Hope that helps,

Comment: but isn't that exactly the opposite of the statement from the lecture? I mean, you're saying that it's a linear functional if it's on a vector space (and Banach space is a vector space)…sorry i'm just very confused now! @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: @GregVoit : Both the domain and codomain are important. An element of the dual space of $V$, $f$, is such that $V$ is a vector space, $f : V \to \mathbb R$ is linear but most importantly the codomain is $\mathbb R$. An arbitrary linear map would have codomain a vector space.

I added an edit.